# "Access denied" writing to samba share on Lubuntu (not all folders)

Tags: permissions, lubuntu, samba

I have a samba share defined on a Lubuntu machine as follows:

```
[Samsung2Tb1]
comment = Samsung 2Tb1
path = /media/Samsung2Tb1
browseable = yes
read only = no
guest ok = yes
force user = user1
```

I've been trying to write files to subfolders of this share from a Windows 10 machine. While I can do this to the first subfolder, when I try to write to any of the others I get an "Access Denied" error.

I've tried adding this to the smb.conf entry:

create mask = 0777
   directory mask = 0777

but it didn't help. I also tried:

```
sudo chown -R user1:user1 /media/Samsung2Tb1
```

but that didn't help either.

Any ideas what else I can try?

Answer (score 0):

I think you have the right cfg but checked it with a wrong sequence.
try again to create a subdir with create mask and directory mask set. if does not work check on server the permissions and owner with

> ls -l

everything should match the main directory.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the feedback. I suspect that a software updated might have borked my samba installation, as I have restored the O/S from a backup (with the same smb.conf file) and the problem has disappeared. Time to stop accepting the updates I think...